# How much reputation do the users have that flag the most to moderate the site?

Tags: support, flags, statistics

And by that I mean the silent majority that reports events. Which group of users reports most of the issues they see on the site? Are they seasoned 3k+ users or the sub 1k users? How are these users distributed with respect to the flags raised?

In SQL terms:

- count total flags grouped by reputation.
- count total flags/count total users grouped by reputation

I'm quite sure it should be divided by flag type, due to certain situations where some users would disproportionately skew the results due to being members of Charcoal.

Comment: Impatience, n: the feeling while you're waiting for Shog9 to see your [meta-tag:statistics] question.

Comment: I'm curious why you are calling out Charcoal here and not other teams that patrol for content that needs moderation. What's the goal behind this request? Additionally, why are you looking for specific user information and not the usual aggregate data that is normally provided with these types of requests?

Comment: @Andy Charcoal is the only group I know that the user doesn't require their users to directly act onto reports allowing them to autoflag post.

Comment: By "moderate the site", do you specifically mean flagging, as opposed to e.g. close voting? If so, it might be worth it to make the title a little more specific. (I realise this comment is a little pedantic, specially given that IIRC close votes are tricky to track down via SEDE -- though I hazard that might be easier for someone like Shog.)

Comment: @duplode If you are asking me that question, I really have to ask: did you read the question?

Comment: @duplode for me, moderation can't be done without reporting. So, yes, reporters (or the ones that get the ball rolling) contribute much much more to the moderation of the site. Without them, the smaller group with privileges, wouldn't be able to focus their actions where they are needed.

Comment: @Braiam Perhaps I worded my comment poorly. I had noticed that you restricted the scope to flagging in the question body, but it wasn't entirely clear why you did so -- you might have been considering flagging as specially relevant in some way, or as a proxy metric for moderation activity in general. In any case, your latest comment does clarify things.

Comment: What is "Charcoal"?  And yes, I did google it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth site: is your friend. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/213575

Comment: While waiting for a CM to reply, you could query SEDE for the rep distribution among the holders of Marshal badge, or Deputy badge.

Comment: @user4412195 the problem with those badges is that hides a ton of users that individually haven't flagged many posts, but grouped they have done a lot of flagging. For example, the group of 5.7k users that got their Deputy badge, but not their Marshal, could at most raised 2.8 million flags, while the ones that got their citizen patrol, but not their Deputy, could have raised 13.2 million flags at most.

Comment: @user4412195 btw, that we know of, the group of deputies and marshal have raised at least 1.9 million flags.

Comment: ProTip: You can [download Charcoal's data](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/dumps) and pretty easily pull whatever information you want about autoflagging (such as if you want to exclude automated flags from your statistics here)

Comment: Since close votes are unlocked at 3k, it would naturally mean that 3k+ users flag less posts since they can close vote themselves instead of flagging.

Comment: @Undo I can't exclude them since I don't know which users flagged how much.

Comment: @Lundin yet another reason to have them "divided by flag type".

Comment: If I understand the profile and SEDE capabilities correctly, someone with SQL knowledge should be able to write up a query, at least for *total flags per user* and plot that against reputation earned, since both of these are publicly available on the profile page.

Comment: @Adriaan The request for specific users has been edited out since I posted the comment. The question has been changed to request aggregate data based on reputation and flag type.

Comment: You can definitely use Metasmoke's data to subtract out autoflags from the flag count for each user -- it keeps flag logs for every user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to answer 1 question here: how many total flags are raised by users in various reputation groups.

Let's go with groups of 1K reputation. And let's ignore folks with > 100000 rep, since there are only 1 user per group in a lot of those groups. So, something like,

```
select round(Reputation, -3, 1) Reputation, count(*) Flags
from Flags f
join Users u on u.Id=f.UserId and u.Id<>-1
where f.CreationDate > getdate()-365
and Reputation < 100000
group by round(Reputation, -3, 1)
order by 1
```

That'll give us this nifty chart:

[image: flags by 1000K rep bucket]

That's fun and all, and you can probably guess the answer to your question... But it's not a very good use for a chart. So instead of plotting the total flag count for each bucket, let's do a % of all flags raised in the past year and then add one of those funky pareto lines with the cumulative percentage:

[image: that pareto thing]

So we can see that 50% is about 9K, 75% is about 28K, <100K only gets us to about 91% of all flags raised - thus 100K+ users cover about 9% in total.

Comment: For Braiam's comment about Charcoal's contribution to this graph, we've only cast 4778 autoflags on SO, all-time. Not even a bump on this graph.

Comment: Cool, now to figure out how many of those flags are close flags. Can you do the same graph but separating the post target? Questions/answers/comments?

Comment: LOL, I read the query and the first graph and wondered "since when do we have a Flags table in SEDE, and why-oh-why can we see *who* cast the flags". Then I scrolled down and saw who posted it ...

Answer (score 16):

Following the [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6655984/user4412195) by Normal Human, here's an interesting graph generated by [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/856263/deputies-grouped-by-reputation#graph).

[image]

1. suspended users
2. [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy?userid=22656)

It's a logarithmic plot, so 3.0 on the x-axis corresponds to 10<sup>3.0</sup> = 1000 reputation. You see that the most deputies (users with 80+ helpful flags) are found just below 3000 reputation (due to the logarithmic scale, the bins for lower reputation are smaller). However, relatively speaking, the higher the reputation of a user, the more likely they are to have a [Deputy badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy). The Marshal badge (500+ helpful flags) follows [a similar pattern](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/856264/marshals-grouped-by-reputation#graph).